# How to set frequency to collection of location updates in Android?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to collect some location updates into an arraylist in an Android map application. I would like to save the collected location updates for every minute into my local server. How can I do this. Is there a function in Android to do this?

Comment: You should be able to use LocationManager for this.  Call [requestLocationUpdates](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates%28java.lang.String,%20long,%20float,%20android.location.LocationListener%29) and specify 60000 for `minTime` parameter.  You will get location updates _approximately_ every minute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use `Service`, which is like an Activity without any UI.
2. Let `Service` run after every minute and take down the location updates in the form of Latitude and Longitude.
3. Then use a `Non-UI` thread to store the location data in the DataBase, for **eg:** `SQLite`

**For service**:

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

**For creation of simple thread:**

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable(){

   public void run(){

           // Here is the code that will do your job every minute.

           // Please use a while loop with a loop control factor,

           // and sleep mechanism to let your thread sleep for a minute.

          // for sleep, instead of using Thread.sleep(timeout) better use     

          //TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(timeout);

     }
  });


t.start();
```

Comment: :can you give me or point me to some code related to this.

Answer (score 0):

We either use **NETWORK_PROVIDER** or **GPS_PROVIDER** to grad the current location.

In both the case there is a method that is listed below to get the time stamped and the distanced based location updates frequently by the app.

The location change will be detected by **OnLocationChange()** called by the LocationListener registered at requestLocationUpdates().

```
public void requestLocationUpdates (String provider, long minTime, float minDistance, LocationListener listener)
```

If minDistance is greater than 0, a location will only be broadcasted if the device moves by minDistance meters. To obtain notifications as frequently as possible, set both parameters to 0.

[For more details and info](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates%28java.lang.String,%20long,%20float,%20android.location.LocationListener%29)

Comment: my question is related to programming the update collection. I need some thing more similar to answer 3. Thank you